# browser-sync disable directory browsing for some sub-directories

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I am new to use of browser-sync and gulp but according to usage i am trying to make my http-server accessible via webserver. Additionally i want to exclude some directories to be hidden or not to be browsed by using negation on files attribute but it does not work... My main goal is to define some directories to give 404 as always whatever is requested from them...

Can someone please check; if possible, here is my gulp implementation:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var files = ['d2cvib/output/**/*.{xml}','!d2cvib/changed-list/**'];
// Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({files,
        port: 8203,
        server: {
            baseDir: "/mule_local_exchange/d2c/",
            middleware: [
            function(req, res, next) {
                const user = 'd2c';
                const pass = 'd2cweb';
                let authorized = false;
                // See if authorization exist in the request and matches username/password
                if (req.headers.authorization) {
                    const credentials = new Buffer(req.headers.authorization.replace('Basic ', ''), 'base64').toString().split(/:(.*)/)
                      if (credentials[0] === user && credentials[1] === pass) {
                          authorized = true;
                      }
                }
                if (authorized) {
                    // Proceed to fulfill the request
                    next();
                } else {
                    // Authorization doesn't exist / doesn't match, send authorization request in the response header
                    res.writeHead(401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Authenticate"'})
                    res.end();
                }
            }

        ],
        directory: true
        }    
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not disable directory listing; but work-aroundly i've disabled response code if some of the directories have been asked by HTTP GET, not %100 clean solution but works for my case:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var cache = require('gulp-cache');

//For conditions of rest-uri patterns
function buildSearch(substrings) {
  return new RegExp(
    substrings
    .map(function (s) {return s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');})
    .join('{1,}|') + '{1,}'
  );
}


gulp.task('clear-cache', function() {
  // Or, just call this for everything
  cache.clearAll();
});

// Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        port: 8203,
        server: {
            baseDir: "/mule_local_exchange/d2c/",
            middleware: [
                function (req, res, next) {
                    const user = 'd2c';
                    const pass = 'd2cweb';
                    var pattern = buildSearch(['changed-list','current', 'changed_list']);
                    let authorized = false;
                    // See if authorization exist in the request and matches username/password
                    if (req.headers.authorization) {
                        const credentials = new Buffer(req.headers.authorization.replace('Basic ', ''), 'base64').toString().split(/:(.*)/)
                        if (credentials[0] === user && credentials[1] === pass) {
                            authorized = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (authorized) {

                        if (pattern.test(req.url)) { //400 for not required directories
                            res.writeHead(400, {'Response':'Bad-request'})
                            res.end();
                        } else { // Proceed to fulfill the request
                            next();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Authorization doesn't exist / doesn't match, send authorization request in the response header
                        res.writeHead(401, {
                            'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Authenticate"'
                        })
                        //res.send(401,{ 'Authentication' : 'Failed' })
                        res.end();
                    }
                }
            ],
            directory: true
        }
    });
});
```

That part does the job:

```
if (pattern.test(req.url)) { //400 for not required directories
                            res.writeHead(400, {'Response':'Bad-request'})
                            res.end();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple `baseDir`s for browsers-sync and the directory listing will only be available for the first one:

```
baseDir: ["/mule_local_exchange/d2c/PUBLIC", "/mule_local_exchange/d2c/", "/some/other/dir"],
directory: true
```

In this example, directory listing will only show contents of `/mule_local_exchange/d2c/PUBLIC"`. All files will still be available from all the dirs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but one point is not clear for me; what do you mean by "/mule_local_exchange/d2c/PUBLIC". All files will still be available from all the dirs." this sentence here ? Can you please shortly explain if possible ?

Comment: When you point your browser to the browserSync url, say `localhost:3000`, it will only show the listing of the **first** folder in the `baseDir`.

Comment: ... but files from all the folders listed in `baseDir` will still be available in your project throgh direct links. If you have a file `main.js` in `/some/other/dir`, it will be available as `localhost:3000/main.js`.